# why input button element does not accept carriage return character in some browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, carriage-return

input element value attribute does not render the carriage return character for some browsers. Like chromium browser in ubuntu operating system and 
IE, Edge browser in windows operating system.
Other browsers correctly render the carriage return in value parameter.

first case :

```
<input type="button" value="some \n text"/>
```

second case:

```
<button type="button" >some <br> text</button>
```

Second case i don't need but it works for all browser. but it wrap automatically the text in the case of more no.of character present in the button element.

Example :

```
<button type="button" >some Lengthy <br> text</button>
```

"Lengthy" word wrap into the new line.

So i leave this method of second case.

I want to get the result using the first case Why it will not work "\n" character only the above i mentioned browsers?

What i do for this problem?

Comment: The correct way to do this is right there in your question: The `button` element and markup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got your point you want a static line wrap in buttons and you are correct *br* tag won't give you that as it may manipulate line breaks depending on its container size.
So what's the issue?.
The issue is some browsers as you may have noticed don't interpret \n properly so in that case you can use the html equivalent of \n instead of \n which is

```
  &#13;&#10;
```